# Algorithms for 2D polygon simplification by collapsing segments?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, polygon, simplify

Recently I've been looking into some different methods of polygon simplification.

Popular methods include [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker path simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm & [Visvalingam](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/), while they are both good algorithms, in some cases gives poor results by only ever removing points, never placing points in new locations *(both a pro and a con depending on the usage)*.

I've been looking into using a simplified segment collapsing method, common for 3D geometry, see: [Surface simplification using quadric error metrics](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=258849).

From some quick tests this works reasonably well, however I suspect this isn't all that novel, possibly there are better methods for 2D polygons too.

I also looked into [PO-Trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace)'s method of polygon simplification, which is excellent, but focused on simplifying polygons extracted from bitmap images.

---

Are there well known algorithms for polygon simplification using segment collapsing?

*Asking because I'm about to write my own function that uses quadric error metrics, but suspect this may exist already, possibly named differently.*

*If not, I'll link the code once its done.*

Comment: One can find an implementation of Quadric error metric simplification for polylines in [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme), see MRPolylineDecimate.h/.cpp

Answer (score 2):

The [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) library provides an implementation of a [polyline simplification](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Polyline_simplification) algorithm.

It is based on the work of [Dyken et al.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10109-009-0078-8).